# Make a file accept only two arguements from the command-line

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments, ksh

Hello I am having a lot of trouble understanding for one, what I am supposed to do and two how I am supposed to implement this. First I will state the step by step process my program is supposed to do.

1)  The script is executed in the Korn shell.

2)  Name the shell script file is asg6s.

3)  The asg6s file is executable and accepts exactly two arguments from the command line.

4)  The asg6s file accepts any two named files as the two arguments that are text files.

5)  Create a file containing  “Message Holder” as the text within the file. This file is entered on the command line as the first argument.

6)  The second argument is a file with whatever name you select that 
accepts the output from the asg6s file.

7)  The command line must have the following: asg6s [input file name] [output file name] before any processing can occur. The input file must contain the words detailed in 5) above. The output file is created at the time the command line is executed, not before.

8)  The script first checks that there are exactly two arguments on the command line. If the command line does not have two arguments, display an error message that includes a suggestion of the pattern on the command line and exit the script.

9)  If the condition in 8) is met, then the script must independently check that the file named by the first argument both exists and contains some text. If the command line does not have as its first argument a file that exists and contains some text, display an error message that includes the name of the file and exit the script.

Ok the following is as far as I have gotten with the code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Reroute to directory of used files
cd /class
#Make the asg6s accept only two arguements
if [[ $# -ne 2 ]];then
    print "Does not equal two arguments"
    exit
fi
#Creates file containing Message Holder
cat message
Message Holder
#File that accepts the output of file message
cp message message1
#Determine if first argument is empty or null
if [ -z "$1"]
    echo "File does not exist"
fi
```

Obviously I am missing something. I think the main thing is I am not setting up the file to accept only two arguments from the command line. Any help would be appreciated. Even if it is links to help me understand what I am not understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. When I read your script I understand dat you have a file `message` in the `/class/cm325d/06/dASG6` folder with the content `Message Holder`. Using `cat message` and showing the output doesn''t belong in your script. You are trying to use that as your argument 1.
I will use ## to explain what I changed or what you could do when you want to improve the script.
I am happy you looked at and debugged the script, not happy I did not write it correct in one time.
The improved script (see # EDIT lines):

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    ## function usage can be called more times, so you write the code on 1 place
    ## I like to add exit in the usage function.
    ## Not correct, I should rename the function to usage_and_exit

# EDIT not "function usage {" but "usage() {"
## There are two ways to declare a function with litthe differences.
## One difference you see here, the value of $0 can be either the functionname 
## or the scriptname.
    usage() {
       ## $0 is replaced by the name of the inputfile
       echo Usage $0 inputfile outputfile 
       ## Escaping double qoutes for showing them
       echo "The inputfile must have the text \"${must_have_text}\""
       ## Use exit 0 when all is OK and exit 1 (or higher) when you have an error
       exit 1
    }

# EDIT Moved this line to be the first lain of the main code.
## Your function usage() must be able to  use the variable!
    must_have_text="Message Holder"

    # Reroute to directory of used files
    cd /class/
    ## When the path is incorrect or you have incorrect rights you get problems.
    ## Checking $? or using || is possible here.

    #Make the asg6s accept only two arguments
    ## I removed the double [ ] brackets, for the -ne check one is enough.
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
       ## ksh is losing from bash. print is only supported in ksh
       ## I prefer using echo
       echo "Does not equal two arguments"
       ## call function usage above, which will also exit
       usage
    fi
    ## Removed the cat message
    ## Introduced a variable with the mandatory test

    #File that accepts the output of file message
    ## Removed line cp message message1, 

    #Determine if first argument is empty or null
    ## Not needed, syntax checking $1 was missing "; then".
    ## When $1 is filled, you want to see if it is a file with -f.
    ## First introduce new variables
    infile=$1
# EDIT outfile should be arg2 not arg1
    outfile=$2
# EDIT Beteween " and ] always a space (stupid keyboard)
    if [ ! -f "${infile}" ]; then
       echo "File ${infile} does not exist"
       ## exit using function again
       usage
    fi
    ## use $() and not `` for executing unix command inside a command line
    if [ $(grep -c "${must_have_text}" ${infile}) -eq 0 ]; then
       echo "${infile} must have 1 or more times the text ${must_have_text}"
       usage
    fi
    cp ${infile} ${outfile}
```

Comment: Tried it I keep getting ./asg6s: line 3: syntax error at line 6: `echo' unexpected. Tried to add quotes but it wouldn't work

Comment: Ok seems like its starting to work better I get: Does not equal two arguments
Usage ./asg6s inputfile outputfile
The inputfile must have the text "Message Holder"

Comment: Did you call it with two arguments like the usage suggests?